# C# Unity, writing a Finite state machine with Animator, but i have a weird loop when the condition stops

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, fsm, animator

Please help why is this looping weird after the condition stops, when the "Bot" finishes his placement, for now just one move down per "Mana" it loops constantly and then just stops as if it is still in that state.

the mana increments at 0.5 and 1 move costs 1 mana

```
    override public void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
{
    animator.SetBool("HasTarget", false);
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find("GM");
    if (GameObject.Find("GM").GetComponent<Placement>().Current_mana >= 1)
    {
    
        go.GetComponent<StateMachineHelper>().SelectUnit.transform.position = 
            go.GetComponent<StateMachineHelper>().SelectUnit.transform.position - new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        go.GetComponent<Placement>().ClickUnit = null;
        go.GetComponent<Placement>().Distance = false;
        go.GetComponent<Placement>().Current_mana--;
    }else//(GameObject.Find("GM").GetComponent<Placement>().Current_mana <= 0.5)
    {

        go.GetComponent<Placement>().ChangeTurn();

        animator.SetBool("IsWaiting", true);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so the answer to my stupid question is...i changed it to OnStateEnter rather than the update one, and just made a new transition to a previous node in the FSM to loop it untill my mana has run out.